# TypeOrm ViewEntity query is incorrect

Tags: mysql, typeorm

I am following the TypeOrm documents on how to create [a ViewEntity](https://typeorm.io/#/view-entities) so I can generate and query a custom view of my database. However at runtime, the SQL generated is not what I expected. The docs mention that the expression fed to `@ViewEntity()` can be a query.  Here is my model:

```
@ViewEntity({
  expression: `
SELECT t1.*, t1.CountOfA + t1.CountOfB AS Total
FROM (
SELECT q.CountOfA, q.CountOfB
FROM questions q
) AS t1`
})
export class CountViewEntity {
  @ViewColumn()
  CountOfA: number;

  @ViewColumn()
  CountOfB: number;

  @ViewColumn()
  Total: number;
}
```

So I expected that the `Repository<CountViewEntity>` would give me one record with CountOfA, CountOfB and Total for each row in my `questions` table.  So I execute this:

```
this.countViewRepository.find();
```

However the following SQL gets generated:

> SELECT `CountViewEntity`.`CountOfA` AS `CountViewEntity_CountOfA`, `CountViewEntity`.`CountOfB` AS `CountViewEntity_CountOfB`, `CountViewEntity`.`Total` AS `CountViewEntity_Total` FROM `count_view_entity` `CountViewEntity`

And I get an error about table `count_view_entity` not existing.

What am I doing wrong?

#### Edit:

hmm... It's been a day since I put up a bounty and the answer/comment I received got me thinking: I'm a MySQL newbie as well as a TypeORM newbie so maybe I just overlooked an assumption the TypeORM docs make.  I thought that the SQL generated would query actual DB tables, but I just reread the docs, in particular this part:

> View entity is a class that maps to a database view

It meant nothing to me before but I've just come across something called [a Database View](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-views-tutorial.aspx).  Maybe I should create one first and then query against that? Feeling optimistic once again...

Comment: Perhaps `CountViewEntity`, not `count_view_entity?

Comment: Don't think I get your suggestion: `count_view_entity` is generated dynamically by TypeORM when it makes the SQL query; it's not something I input anywhere.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**View entity** is a class that maps to a database view. You can create a view entity by defining a new class and mark it with `@ViewEntity()`:

**Updated as per post owner**

Obviously, you must create the [database views](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-views-tutorial.aspx) first before calling it from `TypeORM`, which cause the error `count_view_entity not existing`

`@ViewEntity()` accepts following options:

- `name` - view name. **If not specified, then view name is generated from entity class name.**
- `database` - database name in selected DB server.
- `schema` - schema name.
- `expression` - view definition. **Required parameter**.

> `expression` can be string with properly escaped columns and tables,
>   depend on database used.

Try as below

```
@ViewEntity({
         expression: `
           SELECT t1.*, t1.CountOfA + t1.CountOfB AS Total
           FROM (
                SELECT q.CountOfA, q.CountOfB
                FROM questions q
               ) AS t1`
      })

export class CountViewEntity {

  @ViewColumn()
  CountOfA: number;

  @ViewColumn()
  CountOfB: number;

  @ViewColumn()
  Total: number;
}
```

Do you really need `Sub Query` as there is no point in selecting the same result in outer select.

```
 @ViewEntity({
        expression: `
            SELECT "t1"."CountOfA" AS "CountOfA", "t1"."CountOfB" AS "CountOfB",
                   "t1"."CountOfA" + "t1"."CountOfB" AS "Total"
            FROM "questions" "t1"
               `
            })
```

Also, you can use `QueryBuilder`

```
@ViewEntity({ 
    expression: (connection: Connection) => connection.createQueryBuilder()
        .select("t1.CountOfA", "CountOfA")
        .addSelect("t1.CountOfB", "CountOfB")
        .addSelect("t1.CountOfA" + "t1.CountOfB", "Total")
        .from(questions, "t1")
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions; all 3 of them give me the same result as I see in my original post; the resulting SQL tries to query a table called `count_view_entity` which doesn't exist.  The actual query I want to run is quite a bit more complicated than what I posted; that's why it has a subquery, and also why I didn't use query builder

Comment: Your answer did get me thinking though, and I've posted an update to my original Q

Comment: I can't credit your answer as is because it didn't solve my problem, but you got me thinking about the right things and I eventually got there.  I would be happy to give you the bounty if you revised your answer to one that actually solves my problem.  Basically I had to move my SQL to a database view (i looked up the code to create a view), and then inside the `@ViewEntity()` config, set the view name and change the query to just `SELECT *`

Comment: @BeetleJuice Are you facing issues again? Probably it should solve your problem if not post me the error.

Comment: Hi Vignesh;  no I fixed my issue; I was writing to tell you how I fixed it so you can adjust your answer to explain the fix and get the bounty.  Basically your answer tells me to adjust the `expression` argument but the problem was that I needed to first create a database view on the MySQL server, and then query against that with the expression: `SELECT *`

Comment: @BeetleJuice Happy that your issue resolved. Obviously, you must create the database views first before calling it from `TypeORM`, which cause the error `count_view_entity not existing`.  I have updated my answer as per your suggestion. If is is not right, can you update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this same issue and found that it was a configuration problem so I wanted to share what fixed it for me.

I had "synchronize: false" on my DB connection because DB objects are typically handled outside of TypeORM but I wanted to define an expression for ViewEntities inside the code. But when you disable synchronize on the DB connection it doesn't allow you override it for specific entities.

So I changed my DB connection to allow synchronize and defined a constant that I use on all of my entities with "synchronize: false" then override it with "synchronize: true" on only the ViewEntity.

constants.ts:

```
export const entityDefaults = { 
    database: 'my_db', 
    schema: 'my_schema', 
    synchronize: false
};
```

my-entity.ts:

```
import { Entity } from 'typeorm';
import { entityDefaults } from './constants';

@Entity('my_entity', { ...entityDefaults })
export class MyEntity {
...
```

my-view-entity.ts:

```
import { ViewEntity } from 'typeorm';
import { entityDefaults } from './constants';

@ViewEntity('my_view_entity', { ...entityDefaults, synchronize: true, expression: 'SELECT ...' })
export class MyViewEntity {
...
```

Then when you start the application you should see a message that the view was created.